# How to sign out when another user signs in in React Native with Firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, firebase-authentication

I'm a newbie in React Native and struggling in handling the state of authentication in my app.

I'm using Redux and haven't persisted the authentication state to silently log user in yet. I've added Firebase authentication

Basically what I want is when a user signs in, he will be signed out by the app when that same account signs in in a different device.

Or at least, can we disable the activity of the old user ?

Can anyone please guide me stages and requirements in order to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firebase Auth is designed to allow a user to sign in from multiple devices, and stay signed in until they choose to sign out.  If you want something different, it will require a lot of coding on your part to keep all those devices in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not automatically signout the other/old user but check the authentication token while calling any API by the old user.

While you are logging in from a new device just generates an authentication token on firebase. And from the very next pass that token through header while calling any API.

This is the logic.

Comment: You mean when the new user signs in, the old user can't generate data anymore ? Disabled ?

Comment: For every API call after login, you just need to check the authentication token is right/active/ and current one or not.